# Does Keen.io have a limit keyword or equivalent?

Tags: keen-io

All,

Using Keen.io to pull some analytics.  I allow user input to specify start and end times, but I'm not able to find something equivalent to a "limit" parameter such as can be found for SQL queries.  If a user specifies a large enough range, this can result in way too much data coming back.

Does Keen.io have a way to pull back the first "x" records?

bower.json

`"keen-js": "^3.4.1",`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new  [Keen IO](http://keen.io) API feature released today which allows you to limit your query result to get your "top x results" and have the results ordered by ascending or descending as well. `order_by` works similar to the currently existing `group_by` feature -- you will call `order_by` in your query.

Define a `direction` to sort all of your query's results in either `ASC` or descending order (default ordering is ascending). And use `limit` to tell the API the number of results you'd like returned - whether that is your top 5 or bottom 5 results.

Order By Docs: https://keen.io/docs/api/#order-by

Here's sample JavaScript to illustrate the newly added `order_by` API feature:

```js
import Keen from 'keen-js';

const client = new Keen({
  projectId: 'PROJECT_ID',
  readKey: 'READ_KEY'
});

client
  .query('count', {
    event_collection: 'logins',
    group_by: 'user.email',
    order_by: {'property_name': 'result', 'direction': 'DESC'},
    limit: '5', //this limits your number of results
    timeframe: 'this_14_days'
  })
  .then(res => {
    // Handle results
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Handle errors
  });
```

`order_by` and `limit` has been a top requested by customers - thank you for feedback to help with creating tools and features to [Keen IO's API](https://keen.io/docs/api/).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs it looks like the simplest way to limit results over a [`timeframe`](https://keen.io/docs/api/#timeframe) is to group results into `[interval][1]`s.

It's not a perfect solution in that you end up with grouped data instead of individual records, but does give a guarantee that the results are limited

Comment: I'll run some tests and see if it was what I was looking for, but thank you for taking a look at this regardless.